# Sorted list in NHibernate without sequential numbers

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a sorted list in class Foo. I read that index column have to be sequential and start in 0 and the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

In my case, in `order` column I have 0, 1, 2, 5. So `Foo` objects have a list with length of 6. Positions 3 and 4 are null.

this is the map

```
<list name="Bars" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="Foo_id" />
  <index column="order" />
  <one-to-many class="Bar" />
</list>
```

How can I rewrite the map in order to  remove this null positions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation due to a legacy concept we adopted in our tables: Our index column always starts in **1**, remaining always a nasty null value in position **0** when we retrieve the collection as a list.

The solution for our case was to use these collections as an `ISet` instead.

To keep the order, we now put the [`order-by` attribute in our mappings](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping), and control the index persistence ourselves.

Using your example, that would become:

```
<set name="Bars" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="order">
  <key column="Foo_id" />
  <one-to-many class="Bar" />
</set>
```

*PS: Don't forget to change your collection variable type to `Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet(Of Bar)`*

Comment: You can do the same using a Bag if you don't want your collection to be unique.

Comment: I do not want to seem pedantic, but there is a typo in the code: you forgot to end it as  `</set>` ...(still no help for my particular problem)

Comment: @jmodrak Thank's for noticing. Fixed it!